# Deserialize single string/date from JsonObject to string in java

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I have a serialized json-date. I wonder if I can just deserialize that single string with the json-date like in c#. But how do you do that in java?

Here is the c# code:

```
DateTime dateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(string);
```

Hope someone can help and that I do not need to create a whole class to do this.

Edit:
Here is the string: "/Date(1630050818893+0300)/"

Comment: What java library are you using to work with json?

Comment: What is the shape of the `string` JSON?

Comment: Org.json and Gson. String is here "\/Date(1630050818893+0300)\/"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to deserialize the old .NET text date format, you will have to setup a *GSON* `JsonDeserializer` for the `Date` type.

You can implement one matching and extracting the `timestamp` value out of the `String` date as follows:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("/Date\\((-?\\d+).*\\)/");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final Matcher matcher = DATE_PATTERN.matcher(jsonElement.getAsString());
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            final String timestamp = matcher.group(1);
            return new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(jsonElement.getAsString() + " does not match /Date(timestamp)/ pattern");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then register the custom `DateDeserializer` as your `java.util.Date` type deserializer (given that you are using this type in your POJO type):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
        .create();
ObjectWithDate objectWithDate = gson.fromJson(json, ObjectWithDate.class);
```

Where `ObjectWithDate` is a template object holding a `java.util.Date` field:

```
public class ObjectWithDate {

    private final Date date;

    public ObjectWithDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectWithDate{" +
                "date=" + date +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be making a mistake. I did this: String json = "/Date(1630050818893+0300)/"; String objectWithDate = gson.fromJson(json, String.class); And got this error for the String objectWithDate line: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Indeed you made a mistake as the input you provided *is not valid JSON*. The input would be something as follows: `"{\"date\":\"\\/Date(1630050818893+0300)\\/\"}"` where `date` would be a field in your Java type.

Comment: Forgive me for my lack of knowledge. Now I tried this: String objectWithDate = gson.fromJson("{\"date\":\"\\/Date(1630050818893+0300)\\/\"}", String.class); And got this error: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: I have already updated my answer. You cannot deserialize a JSON object as being a `String` object. It should be following the example note: `Date date = gson.fromJson("{\"date\":\"\\/Date(1630050818893+0300)\\/\"}", ObjectWithDate.class).getDate();`